# IEnumerable multiple enumeration caused by contract precondition

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, validation, code-contracts

I have an `IEnumerable` parameter that is required to be non-empty. If there's a precondition like the one below then the collection will be enumerated during it. But it will be enumerated again the next time I reference it, thereby causing a "Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable" warning in Resharper.

```
void ProcessOrders(IEnumerable<int> orderIds)
{
    Contract.Requires((orderIds != null) && orderIds.Any());  // enumerates the collection

    // BAD: collection enumerated again
    foreach (var i in orderIds) { /* ... */ }
}
```

These workarounds made Resharper happy but wouldn't compile:

```
// enumerating before the precondition causes error "Malformed contract. Found Requires 
orderIds = orderIds.ToList();
Contract.Requires((orderIds != null) && orderIds.Any());
---
// enumerating during the precondition causes the same error
Contract.Requires((orderIds != null) && (orderIds = orderIds.ToList()).Any());
```

There are other workarounds that would be valid but maybe not always ideal like using ICollection or IList, or performing a typical if-null-throw-exception.

Is there a solution that works with code contracts and IEnumerables like in the original example? If not then has someone developed a good pattern for working around it?

Comment: I think it's probably just a bad idea to have a contract dependant on an IEnumerable - as IEnumerables by definition can incur side effects.

Comment: So far I've used ICollection as a workaround and never had a problem, though I'm curious if there's a solution for IEnumerables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use one of the methods designed to work with `IEnumerable`s, such as [`Contract.Exists`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412869):

> Determines whether an element within a collection of elements exists within a function.
>
> **Returns**
>
> true if and only if predicate returns true for any element of type T in collection.

So your predicate could just return `true`.

---

```
Contract.Requires(orderIds != null);
Contract.Requires(Contract.Exists(orderIds,a=>true));
```

Comment: Will this not also enumerate the `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Only if you a) Have enabled Runtime checking, and b) Haven't selected "Skip Quantifiers". (Although, in such a case, I'd recommend splitting into two `Requires`)

Comment: Ah OK. So would it be correct to say that neither the original code nor your code _actually_ cause an enumeration (modulo your a and b above), but ReSharper doesn't realise this in the original code, and your code just puts it in a form that RS ignores?

Comment: @Rawling - correct - without the runtime checking, all of the code inside calls to `Contract` methods is removed. So, it's just a way to hide it better from Resharper.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However Resharper still complains whether runtime checking is on or not. Any idea how to get Resharper to happily accept this? I had already added an annotations file for code contracts per [these instructions](http://www.infinitec.de/post/2010/11/18/Using-Code-Contracts-Visual-Studio-and-with-Resharper.aspx) which clears up a lot of contract issues with RS but apparently it doesn't cover Contract.Exists.

Comment: @Keith - I think you might have to take it up with the RS developers at this point - it's quite contextual though, so may be difficult to analyze.